# Loading sliders into a div with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load several different sliders within a `div` with AJAX but the sliders need JavaScript code and do not run the `show`.

Principal PHP document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BLOG</title>
<link href="estilo-pagina-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider1').cycle({
        fx:      'fade', //'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight,scrollUp',blindX, blindY, blindZ, cover, curtainX, curtainY, fade, fadeZoom, growX, growY, none, scrollUp,scrollDown,scrollLeft,scrollRight,scrollHorz,scrollVert,shuffle,slideX,slideY,toss,turnUp,turnDown,turnLeft,turnRight,uncover,ipe ,zoom
        speed:   '600',
        timeout: '7000',
        next:    '#next',
        prev:    '#prev',
        pager:   '#thumb',
        pauseOnHover: false,                 // if you hover pauses the slider
        startClockOnMouseOut: false,         // if clock should start on MouseOut
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="43" height="29" /></a></li>';
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script>
function nuevoAjax() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function Cargar(url) {
    var centro_galeria = document.getElementById('centro_galeria');
    ajax = nuevoAjax();
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            centro_galeria.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#contenedor {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
<link href="estilo-galeria.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="button" >
        <ul class="menu-galeria">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="Cargar('galeria1.php');">GALERIA1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="Cargar('galeria2.php'');">GALERIA2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="centro_galeria"><?php include("galeria1.php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`galeria1.php`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div id="slider1">
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/2.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/3.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/4.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/5.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/6.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="thumb"></ul>
    <div id='next' class="slider_next">
        <img src="imagenes-presentacion/next.png" width="78" height="100" alt="next image" />
    </div>
    <div id='prev' class="slider_prev">
        <img src="imagenes-presentacion/prev.png" width="78" height="100" alt="previous image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`galeria2.php`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div id="slider1">
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/2.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/2.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/3.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/4.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/5.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/6.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
            <img src="imagenes-galeria/7.jpg" />
        </div>
        <ul id="thumb"></ul>
        <div id='next' class="slider_next">
            <img src="imagenes-presentacion/next.png" width="78" height="100" alt="next image" />
        </div>
        <div id='prev' class="slider_prev">
            <img src="imagenes-presentacion/prev.png" width="78" height="100" alt="previous image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you should always use `<script type="text/javascript">`. `type` attribute is required and `language` attribute is not a part of XHTML 1.0, it’s just a legacy feature supported in Transitional DTD for compatibility. But the best solution is (especially in XHTML) separation of JavaScript code to a file and linking that file via `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`. Note that in inline scripts (not in separate file) you must encode `<` and `&` as `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively, or use CDATA section. CDATA section breaks the code when HTML (not XML) parser is used.

Comment: ajax generated content works, what does not work is the javascript to be executed in galeria2

Comment: Instead of `onclick="Cargar('galeria2.php'');"` try `onclick="Cargar('galeria2.php');"` – you typed the final single-quote twice.

Comment: BTW directly inside `galeria2.php` there is no JavaScript code. Even if it was, it would not be executed. See [`innerHtml` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML).

Comment: fixed the bug of the quotes, it is strange even so work the ajax, but the content of the slider javascript I want to load in galeria2 does not work, shows some pictures over others: _S

Comment: The `$('#slider1').cycle(…)` is called when document is ready, i.e. when DOM tree of the original document is constructed. It contains no `#slider1` yet as you load it asynchronously. You should call the `cycle` method after setting the `innerHtml` in `onreadystatechange` handler.

Comment: After fetching any `JavaScript` contents with `Ajax` it will not work.Because dynamically loaded JavaScript need to get bound again. The simple way to do this is to put your JavaScript code in one Function and call it again after ajax is success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) :

```
function Cargar(url) {
    $('#centro_galeria').load(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BLOG</title>
<link href="estilo-pagina-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 MySlider();
});
function MySlider()
{
    $('#slider1').cycle({
        fx:      'fade', //'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight,scrollUp',blindX, blindY, blindZ, cover, curtainX, curtainY, fade, fadeZoom, growX, growY, none, scrollUp,scrollDown,scrollLeft,scrollRight,scrollHorz,scrollVert,shuffle,slideX,slideY,toss,turnUp,turnDown,turnLeft,turnRight,uncover,ipe ,zoom
        speed:   '600',
        timeout: '7000',
        next:    '#next',
        prev:    '#prev',
        pager:   '#thumb',
        pauseOnHover: false,                 // if you hover pauses the slider
        startClockOnMouseOut: false,         // if clock should start on MouseOut
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="43" height="29" /></a></li>';
        }
    });
}
</script>
<script>
function nuevoAjax() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function Cargar(url) {
    var centro_galeria = document.getElementById('centro_galeria');
    ajax = nuevoAjax();
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            centro_galeria.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
           MySlider();
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#contenedor {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
<link href="estilo-galeria.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="button" >
        <ul class="menu-galeria">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="Cargar('galeria1.php');">GALERIA1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="Cargar('galeria2.php'');">GALERIA2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="centro_galeria"><?php include("galeria1.php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```